# Nested ScrollView - layout behavior

Tags: android

I have a Nested Scrollview in which I have a GridView.
For nested scrollview I got this:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

I looked in the string directory, but there is no string named "appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" and I don't have any errors.

Where can I find the string named "appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"?

Comment: why do you need it ?

Comment: That string is defined in the support library's string.xml file.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav Thank you very much.